# Share Point 2010: I copied a site from a location to another

Tags: permissions, content-query-web-part

I just copied a site from 1 location to another in Share Point 2010.  However I am experiencing some issues with the permissions and user access.

I noticed that the permissions cannot be copied so i stopped inheriting permissions for the site so it now has unique permissions.

But On the home page, I built a content query web part, but only I, site administrator can see the webpart.  Even if i grant a full control to a user, the web part is just not visible.

Is that an issue with the permission itself?

Should I re create the web part?

Could you please assist on this issue please?

Thank ou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Audience targeting for that web part. you sure you have not given any group name in the webpart. If it is a publishing site. have you published the page after adding the webpart? If it is in draft(or check out) state, it wont be visible to the users. Go to the library where page is residing and check all these properties. Ideally user should be able to see the web part.

Comment: Hello Ankit,
I've checked all these properties, the page is published, there is no group specified in the audience filtering settings of the web part, still the web part does not appear.

Comment: Create a separate page and check. Will be confirmed if its a migration issue or the issue with the particular site.